# What kind of analysis can someone perform given a swap rate curve of a currency pair at different times?

Tags: machine-learning, data-visualization, data-mining, inference, finance

The dataset that I have looks like the one attached - any ideas on how data like this can be used to extract anything meaningful?

I would appreciate any help or ideas you might have.

Thanks in advance[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7SkD.png)

Comment: Cannot read the spreadsheet.

Comment: Let me know how I can help: Are you able to understand at least the form of the dataset from the shapshot?

Answer (score 0):

- Look at whether your curve is trending upward or downward
- Compare your swap with one with high default probabilities
- Compare with the OIS curves
- Use it to calibrate Libor Market Model for Swaptions
- Plot the curve for the term structures
- Compare with your calibrated HullWhite short rates

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question! Regarding your first point (find out the trend): I would like to do such an analysis, but it seems that we have multiple datapoints (bidpoints, askpoints) for the same effective period. Do you think that this is normal or there is something wrong with the dataset?